# Section .shstrtab not having flag for containing null-terminated strings

Tags: elf

`readelf -S a.out` outputs:

```
[Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Ar
[ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
[ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048060 000060 000013 00  AX  0   0 16
[ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        08048074 000074 00000b 00   A  0   0  4
[ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00007f 000019 00      0   0  1
```

The type of .shstrtab is **STRTAB**. But it has no flags set. For /bin/true it's similar.

`Flag: SHF_STRINGS: Contains null-terminated strings`
`Type: SHT_STRTAB: String table`

Well, it seems to be redundant. Is the String flag ever used independently of the String type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see the `SHF_STRINGS` attribute in the [*System V Application Binary Interface, Edition 4.1*](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf) (draft, March 18, 1997) document (found when looking through [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)), but did find it listed in [*System V ABI Update (October 2009)*](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.sheader.html); it was apparently added in the [second draft (May 3, 1999)](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/revision.html), but the revision history doesn't indicate why it was added. It appears that this was introduced along with the `SHF_MERGE` attribute, possibly so that string tables and non-string tables don't accidentally get merged(?). However, as far as I could find there were no references to `SHF_STRINGS` outside of string tables (and how `SHF_MERGE` is affected by entries marked by `SHF_STRINGS`), nor in the LSB or architecture-specific documentation.

So, in theory it looks like the `SHF_STRINGS` attribute could be used to mark sections other than a string table that contain null-terminated strings, but I didn't see any times when that happened. Maybe someone made use of the provision, but I couldn't find any example of this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't see the reference to `SHF_STRINGS` in the description of the merge attribute. I finally found good resources: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E26506/ggdlu.html and https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/specialsections.html It seems .shstrtab is defined to have no attributes. But the .comment section is defined with the flags MERGE and STRINGS (since LSB 5.0.0). I checked with a self-compiled C program and it indeed has these flags set. Although .rodata doesn't have the flags set defined in LSB.